# TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: WorkItemTracking.sql

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

Currenlty, I have installed Team Foundation Server 2012. When I create Team Project Collection, I got following error.

```
TF400744: An error occurred while executing the following script: WorkItemTracking.sql. Failed batch starts on the line 17271. Statement line: 42. Script line: 17312. Error: 102 Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version is 2008 R2 - 10.50.1600.1
Team Foundatin Server version is 2012 - Update 4 - 11.0.61030.0

So how can I handle my error?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution.

I got the error because of my SQL Server version is 2008 R2. So upgraded to service park 2. After that I can create Team Project Collection in TFS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we missed adding a check to require SP1. We added a use of FORCESEEK in the work item tracking SQL that only works with SP1 or newer for SQL 2008 R2.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wlennon/archive/2013/11/27/tfs-2012-update-4-fails-in-workitemtrackingtodev11m55-sql-on-sql-server-2008-r2-rtm.aspx